# Does a tourist guide make a welcome speech or talk? Which one is proper?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

1. A tourist guide makes a welcome talk to a tourist group on the coach.
2. A tourist guide makes a welcome speech to a tourist group on the coach.
   Which one is proper, a welcome talk or a welcome speech?

Comment: maybe introductory/opening speech?

Comment: Hello, Andrew, thanks for the reply.  Yes, it sounds better. Then what about introductory/opening talk as speech sounds more formal?

Comment: We say _make a speech_ but _**give** a talk_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine, "speech" seems to be slightly more common on google. A "speech" is a little more formal: The guide stands at the front and speaks her prepared text. Politicians give "speeches" in parliament.

A talk is slightly more like a lesson, with opportunities for questions and answers. YOu might go to a talk given by a Professor of History.

I'd actually prefer a slightly different construction using a participle.

> The tourist guide gave a speech/talk welcoming the group to the tour.

Comment: Hello, James, thank you for the reply too. I would like to make sure whether a welcome talk is appropriate in the context.